# Some things I don't quite understand about partitioning for an installation

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, ssd

So I'm installing ubuntu onto my main desktop, but I don't quite understand the partitioning and how Ubuntu works in general.

I have 4 SSDs which I would like to put into a JBOD array. I did some research and found out I can make one partition which goes over all four drives so I can install Ubuntu onto them, as if they were one drive. I want to have all of my programs installed onto the SSDs (/etc/dev/ if I understand correctly) while my HDD should hold /home/.

1. Is the root partition the partition in which the programs are saved in? If not, on which partition is /etc/dev/ saved?
2. How do I make one large partition over 4 drives?
3. I have 12gb of RAM. Do I need to make a swap partition?

I don't have any other OS' installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but let me try to tackle some of your questions.

When installing Ubuntu with separate partitions there are generally four partitions you want to create.

Your root, boot, swap and home partitions.

Your root partition is where everything important is stored, including program files.

To install your partitions over four drives

When installing Ubuntu select the option that allows you to define your partitions manually.

The basic idea will be to create identical partition layouts on each drive. The boot partition should be the first and have the boot flag on. Followed by swap (you want a swap partition, but it doesn't have to be big 1GB should do it), and then root(the rest of your space). You don't have to create a home partition since you want it on your HDD. Do the same (exact) thing for each disk.

Then you want to configure the software raid. 
Do some research on what type of raid you want.

To configure the software raid you want to define the like partitions across each drive, as that partition to use in the RAID array.

ex. sdx1 is the swap partition on each drive. so select sda1,sdb1, sdc1 and sdd1 to use as the swap partition.

If any of this made sense and your were able to get your OS installed across four drives, all thats left to do is mount your hdd at `/home`. `sudo mount /dev/sdxx /home`